# Change the school or schools?

Tags: sentence-construction, singular-vs-plural

Consider something like you want to transfer from school A to school B.

Now consider the following:

> 1. You can change the school if you have the admission from the school B.
> 2. You can change the school**s** if you have the admission from the school B.

I heard the plural form when two people were talking. I am actually not sure which one is correct or if both are correct, or what's the difference, or why they used the plural form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action of changing involves both schools, so:

> **You can change schools** if you have the admission from the school B.

I wouldn't use "have the admission". Better might be "if you can be admitted to school B", "met the admission requirements of school B", or such.

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting. By "having" the admission I meant having the admission letter though or admission offer or something like that.

Comment: "You can change schools if you have an admission *letter* from school B." makes sense.